# What was Boba Fett's intention in the holiday special cartoon?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-holiday-special

Watching the cartoon section in the Star Wars holiday special, I couldn't understand what Boba Fett was actually trying to do

I understand that he was trying to hand over the rebels to Darth Vader, but his method doesn't make sense

Luke and Han were sort of unconscious in the ship, while he was able to take Chewie to a city with a lot of storm-troopers

But instead of turning Chewie over to them and going back to the ship to get Han and Luke, he actually takes the antidote for the sleep virus over to the ship and even revives them, then just runs away without a fight

**What exactly was he trying to do?**

Comment: You see, what he was actually doing was...oh wait, this is the Holiday Special. Nevermind - there is no logic to be found in any of that ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell Exactly, there was no discernable intention of anybody in that, it's even doubtful anyone can find any sense in having the Holiday Special at all.....

Comment: in all honestly - it is entirely possible that when the....thing...was made, (it was 1978 after all - two years before ESB was released), that A:) Lucas hadn't even really figured out Fett's character yet (if he even created him, it could be a Kasdan creation), or B:) the creatives running the cartoon (Lucas had very little involvement with production of the ... thing...) had very scant information to go on and so they ran their own ideas of the character

Comment: but the cartoon is the best part in the whole movie

Comment: also, they make it clear in the cartoon that Boba Fett is the best bounty hunter in the galaxy through Vader's dialogue

Comment: You can be "the best" and still be terrible.  If all the others are even worse.

Comment: Chewbacca explains about 28 mins in. `Raaah ruh ruh ruh grrraaaahl. Beyaaa!`

Comment: George Lucas is trying to moderate this question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is fairly simple. Boba Fett works for Darth Vader, and Vader wants **location of secret Rebel base**. In order to gain Rebels confidence, Boba helps them with monster and with antidote for the virus. Chewie is suspicious of Boba's true intentions, but Boba could not just hand him over to stormtroopers because that would ruin his cover when he gets back without Chewie. Also, stormtroopers do not know he is working for Vader - they shoot at him. It does make sense, because his mission is a secret, and true identity of spies is not revealed to every grunt in the army . Even in real world spies sometimes have to fight their own troops in order to gain confidence of enemy.

Unfortunately for Boba, C-3PO and R2D2 already discovered his true identity. He doesn't want to fight all of the Rebels, so he just escapes. In this way his character is left alive for movies, and he is introduced as "best bounty hunter in Galaxy" . So actually this cartoon has much more sense then rest of Star Wars holiday special.

You could see part where Vader asks from Boba to discover location of Rebel base here at 58:08

Comment: The video link is labeled "The Star Wars Holiday Special (High Quality)" I think that may be greatly overstating the quality of that particular production.